# VueJS Component not rendering in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I have a little Vue app like so:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <statistic
        class-name="stat-1"
        :amount="amount"
        :postfix="postfix"
        :prefix="prefix"
        :scale="scale"
        :accuracy="accuracy"></statistic>
    </div>
    <div><!-- controls --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('statistic', {
  props: ['amount', 'postfix','scale', 'className', 'accuracy', 'prefix','fill'],

  /* config here */

  template:`<div class="animated-statistic" :class="className">
    <svg class="animated-statistic--graphic"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(249,232,154);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(229,107,233);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" :r="radius" fill="url(#grad1)"></circle>
    </svg>
    <div class="animated-statistic--text" v-text="value"></div>
  </div>`
});
```

This is working nicely – [link to working Codepen](https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/live/7692cf199b00bdc5b9ddcfa3edf2668e)

However if you follow that same link in IE11 there is a blank area where the component should be. Unless I'm using IE incorrectly I can't see any errors in the console.

Initially I thought maybe it was a problem with the SVG in IE, but I made [another copy of the pen](https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/live/rKxRGZ) with a static SVG and it is rendering.

If you inspect element in IE11 you just see the `<statistic></statistic>` tag - they aren't being rendered.

[image]

Am I using something that IE doesn't support with this component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see error in Vue object here:

```
Vue.component('statistic-animation', {
  props: ['amount', 'postfix','scale', 'className', 'accuracy', 'prefix','fill'],
  data(){   // ERROR!
    return {
       current : this.amount,
    }
  },
 ....
```

IE 11 does not support short method definition syntax in objects - [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Comment: Thank you. I wrongly assumed that Codepen was using Bable to uglify everything... my mistake! I have it working now. Thanks.

Comment: I had a Vue script that I was using as a component of a site (not the whole thing) and it was not compiled. This answer saved me in IE11. Thank you!